# Tax deduction for penalty paid

Tags: income-tax, india

Can I get tax deduction for my 2 Lakhs penalty paid to the company to break H1B bond. Is there any section I can mention about this 2 lakhs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you can't claim this benefit. This will be the money paid after taxes.